# willFinishLaunchingWithOptions not called

Tags: ios, swift3, swrevealviewcontroller

My app has an app delegate and I have put code in there that I need to be there under the following method in the delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                          willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool{
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialFrontViewController: ViewController2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "initialFrontRevealController") as! ViewController2
    let revealController: RevealViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "revealVC") as! RevealViewController
    revealController.setFront(initialFrontViewController, animated: true)

    print("seen command")

    return true
}
```

My problem is that my print statement doesn't print to the console and none of the tasks I have put in the method actually go in to effect when I build and run my app.

So far I have tried several content and settings resets but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are also having some errors **before** the print statement but you didn't say about. Otherwise it's impossible for the print statement to not print. Like you have had a crash because of the forced unwrapped you did using `as!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code `"print("seen command")"` to the first line in fund

```
application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool
```

Observe whether there is a print log, Out of the current methods can not run the code error.